# Accessing Graph Explorer through powershell

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

does anyone have good tips on how to use graph explorer through PowerShell?    We are trying to automate Gets / Patch commands that done in Microsoft Graph and struggling to get good info on how its achieved through scripts.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Graph Explorer is a web app that doesn't have any hooks that you can use from PowerShell. Try https://github.com/gscales/Exch-Rest if you want to call Graph from PowerShell.

Comment: I guess I should explain more.   I currently have an application in AzureAD I must customize through Graph Explorer.     Its a workaround MS gave me while they finalize the AzureAD interface for that app.     I am trying to push that through code so looking for a way to interact with Graph from PowerShell.    Specifically get application and patch application.

Comment: What do you want to patch? Powershell already has ``Get-AzureRmADApplication`` and ``Set-AzureRmADApplication`` and related cmdlets.

Comment: Graph Explorer is not intended to be used as a management tool. It doesn't provide a programmatic interface. We are working on a Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK. It will be available soon.

Comment: Powershell SDK, as mentioned, was released https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell. You can install it from PowerShell Gallery https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph/0.9.1